# Changing Mediawiki PAGENAME independently from URL

Tags: mediawiki

There is some page in Mediawiki:

```
/wiki/index.php/some_page
```

and the page name (under article and discussion tabs) is the same, but without underscore:

```
some page
```

Is it possible to change displayed page name without changing url? And if yes, then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [{{DISPLAYTITLE}}](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aMagic_words#Technical_metadata) magic word and [$wgRestrictDisplayTitle](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgRestrictDisplayTitle).